# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, backend

Im develop a react website with node js backend than react show some error link [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9geld.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not useing cors or same url for frondend and backend thats why this error coming .For send  data frontend  to  sarver  you need use "cors" package.
install cors:

```
        npm install cors
```

then requre it index.js file

```
        const cors = require('cors')
         app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 0):

That's to do with the backend. Your server isn't set up to receive requests from the URL you're using (localhost). If you're the one writting the server, look up [the cors npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to enable cross site requests. Otherwise, ask whoever is the author of the server.